# How to know who goes on pages?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'm new in C#, specifically in MVC.
I want to return a view with a model like that :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View(db.MyModel.Where(a => a.EmployeID == m_idEmployee));
}
```

for a specific employee (where `m_idEmployee` is the `id` of employee/user, but for the moment, it's a value that I set myself)

I don't use the `loggingaccount` method from visual studio (not very clear for me)

So I want to know if I can "pass" value in Index to set `m_idEmployee` (from my View for example).

Comment: If this is part of an intranet like application, I would really encourage you to spent some time on the security methods that are available out of the box. In an Intranet application the Windows authentication is really handy. Just create a sample project from Visual Studio and specify that you would like to use Windows Authentication to get your hands on a working example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the employee id to your Index method like:

```
public ActionResult Index(int empId)
{
   return View(db.MyModel.Where(a => a.EmployeID == empId));
}
```

you have to change the way you call the Index method accordingly by passing it as query string or alternatively change the verb to post; the [`model binder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder(v=vs.118).aspx) will take care of it.

Modelbinder quick ref:

> Maps a browser request to a data object. This class provides a
>   concrete implementation of a model binder.

Comment: Thanks for the fast rep !

Comment: @Jeflow you are welcome, if your questions has solved please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself

Answer (score 1):

Change your controller method to:

```
public ActionResult Index(int employeeId)
```

Then create an action in your view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Text of the link", "Index", "NameOfYourController", new { employeeId = 123 })
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast rep !

Answer (score 1):

you can create a Class return value in a class independente

and call the function in your controller class like this

EmployerModel.class

```
public findEmployerById(int id){
return db.MyModel.Where(a => a.EmployeID == id);
}


public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
   return View(new EmployerModel().findEmployerById(id));
}
```

and in your view you need to add

```
@model package.MyModel
```